# force timer event again without waiting timer loop finish

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am trying to force serialport `(SerialPort1.WriteLine(":01050503FF00F3" + vbCr + vbLf)` by using timer but I want to start timer without wait to finish interval time of timer. I put two drawing into question first one is normal `timer.tick` process.
second drawing explain what I try to do. Making interval time 1 second doesn't solve my problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRFHX.png)[image]

Comment: Have you really thought about this? Don't you write code that does something without waiting for a `Timer` all the time? Why would this be any different? If you want to do something now then do it now. If you want to do something when a `Timer` raises its `Tick` event then do it then too. Why would you think that you couldn't do both?

Comment: Just call your Tick event handler directly instead of waiting for the Timer to do it for you.